# Number of repeating of each letter

Tags: c++, numbers, counting

Do you know how to find the number of repeating of each letter in a word in C++?
For example the word is MISSISSIPPI.

M - 1

I - 4

S - 4

P - 2

Answer (score 6):

Since this is almost surely homework, I will only give the overall picture.

Sure, create a vector, one for each possible letter (since you are speaking English, probably a 26 position vector will be enough). Initialize all positions to zero.

Run all over the string, for each letter, add one for each position to the vector corresponding to the letter in the position of the string you are reading. For example, if you are reading an 'a', sum 1 to the first position. For a 'b', sum 1 to the second position, and so on. Mind you, you should not care about upper cases and lower cases.

Reached the end of the string? Fine. Now run all over the vector and show the count for each non-zero position. You can put the corresponding letter to its side.

Remember that all simple letters are in alphabetic order in ASCII/Latin1/UTF-*, so 'a' will give you the number of the corresponding letter. ( x - 'a' ) will give you the position of the letter in the vector. Don't be curious about which exact value is, that would not be portable.

Comment: Thank you,man! No, this's not a homework!I just want to understand how to do such operations, cause I'm not familiar with C++. I'm a newcomer.

Comment: If understanding is just what you really needed, then I'm happy to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Use maps... Choose for yourself whether to take care of uppercase/lowercase and punctuation/other symbols.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word = "MISSISSIPPI";
    map<char,int> charCount;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<word.size(); i++)
        charCount[word[i]]++;

    for (map<char, int>::iterator it = charCount.begin(); it != charCount.end(); ++it)
        cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why map? Vector should be sufficient

Comment: Well, vector should work fine too, I just like maps, then he doesn't have to deal with where to put it. It will put everything in order for him.

Comment: You don't need the `if/else` since when you access the index it is created and default initialized (to `0`). So `charCount[c]++` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const int N = 26;//number of characters in the alphabet
    int count[N];
    char *str = "MISSISSIPPI";

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) count[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
            ++count[str[i]-'a'];
        else if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
            ++count[str[i] - 'A'];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << (char)('a'+i) << " - " << count[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fails badly if string contains any characters other than A..Z, a..z

Comment: You may make an array of 256 elements

Comment: Yes, you may - or you could use `isalpha()` from `ctypes.h` to check your character before trying to update the histogram. As it is though the code is not a very good programming example.

Comment: accept the critics, code edited a bit